# Want to use my API to http which redirects to https

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, https

I am currently using the following public & open-source API

- http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/IT.png

Here, this API is working in the localhost but after deploying it to the `vercel`, it is getting transferred from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` and showing undefined results.

#### What I had done?

I had found a solution which told to add

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

in the `/public/index.html`.

But it still shows the following error

[image: flag]

Is there a solution to tackle this problem? Please help me!

Comment: The site simply does not support HTTPS. As the project seems to be dead (the project page points to code.google.com which is gone for years) I would strongly recommend to use a different API to get the flags you want. A collection of flags should be small enough to include it in your won web space, so no external dependencies are needed.

Comment: Suggest me any good API  ?